# How to set default display as year wise in Android Dialog datepicker

Tags: android, android-datepicker

I am trying to figure out how to set default display year wise in Android Dialog `DatePicker`. Our scenario is first user have to select the year then month and finally date in dialog `DatePicker`. For this requirement we need to open year wise display on opening of the dialog.

PFB Image link. Kindly refer to right side image which should open by default.

[image: DatePicker]

Comment: You can create a custom view by extending `DatePicker` class.

Comment: thanks for your reply but i dont need a custom view in date picker i need to use the same view only the requirement is to open year view by default.

Comment: Have you already succeeded in opening the dialog with year by default? The accepted answer just sets the default value for the year.

Comment: Do you find an answer? I also have this problem.

Comment: create a custom view dialog (reference     compile 'com.afollestad.material-dialogs:core:0.9.2.3'
) with two tabs. in first tab display the list of years which you need to create manually on onclick of that list you can enable the second tab show him calendar from any library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use Calendar and subtract years you want , for example:

```
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle saveInstanceState)
{
    final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    c.add(Calendar.YEAR, -18);
    int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

    return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, year, month, day);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Below is the property of DatePickerDialog by which you achieve this use case

```
dpDialog.getDatePicker().getTouchables().get(0).performClick();
```

Answer (score 0):

***Implement your activity  :***

implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener  {

**in  onCreate  when you click on button to get datepicker dialog :**

```
calendar2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // Initialize a new date picker dialog fragment
        DialogFragment dFragment = new DatePickerFragment();
      //  calendar2.setText(dateDisplay);
        // Show the date picker dialog fragment
        dFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "Date Picker");
    }
});
```

**Outside oncreate**

```
@Override
public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day) {
  //  Calendar cal = new GregorianCalendar(year, month, day);
    month = month + 1;
    Log.d ( TAG, "onDateSet: mm/dd/yyy: " + month + "/" + day + "/" + year );
    String date = day + "/" + month + "/" + year;
 //   mDisplayDate.setText ( date );
    setDate(date);
}
private void setDate(String date) {
  //  final DateFormat dateFormat = DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.MEDIUM);
    ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.calendar2))
            .setText(date);
}




 public static class DatePickerFragment extends DialogFragment implements android.app.DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {
        @Override
        public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            final Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
            int year = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
            int month = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
            int day = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
            /*
                Create a DatePickerDialog using Theme.
                    DatePickerDialog(Context context, int theme, DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener listener,
                        int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth)
             */
            // DatePickerDialog THEME_DEVICE_DEFAULT_LIGHT
//            android.app.DatePickerDialog dpd = new android.app.DatePickerDialog(getActivity(),
//                    AlertDialog.THEME_DEVICE_DEFAULT_LIGHT, this, year, month, day);
          android.app.DatePickerDialog dpd = new android.app.DatePickerDialog(getActivity(),
                            R.style.DatePickerDialogTheme,  (DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener)getActivity(), year, month, day);
//            new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), AlertDialog.THEME_DEVICE_DEFAULT_LIGHT,
//                    (DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener)
//                            getActivity(), year, month, day)
            // DatePickerDialog THEME_DEVICE_DEFAULT_DARK
            android.app.DatePickerDialog dpd2 = new android.app.DatePickerDialog(getActivity(),
                    AlertDialog.THEME_DEVICE_DEFAULT_DARK, this, year, month, day);
            // DatePickerDialog THEME_HOLO_LIGHT
            android.app.DatePickerDialog dpd3 = new android.app.DatePickerDialog(getActivity(),
                    AlertDialog.THEME_HOLO_LIGHT, this, year, month, day);
            dpd.getDatePicker().getTouchables().get(0).performClick();
            // DatePickerDialog THEME_HOLO_DARK
            android.app.DatePickerDialog dpd4 = new android.app.DatePickerDialog(getActivity(),
                    AlertDialog.THEME_HOLO_DARK, this, year, month, day);
            // DatePickerDialog THEME_TRADITIONAL
            android.app.DatePickerDialog dpd5 = new android.app.DatePickerDialog(getActivity(),
                    AlertDialog.THEME_TRADITIONAL, this, year, month, day);
//            TextView tv = new TextView(getActivity());
//
//            // Create a TextView programmatically
//            ViewGroup.LayoutParams lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
//                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, // Width of TextView
//                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT); // Height of TextView
//            tv.setLayoutParams(lp);
//            tv.setPadding(10, 10, 10, 10);
//            tv.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
//            tv.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP,20);
//            tv.setText(getResources().getText(R.string.Date_Of_Birth));
//            tv.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#ff0000"));
//            tv.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FFD2DAA7"));
            // Set the newly created TextView as a custom tile of DatePickerDialog
            //dpd.setCustomTitle(tv);
            // Or you can simply set a tile for DatePickerDialog
            /*
                setTitle(CharSequence title)
                    Set the title text for this dialog's window.
            */
            dpd3.setTitle(getResources().getText(R.string.Date_Of_Birth));
            // Return the DatePickerDialog
            return dpd;
        }
        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day){
            // Do something with the chosen date
        month = month + 1;
        Log.d ( TAG, "onDateSet: mm/dd/yyy: " + month + "/" + day + "/" + year );
     //   dateDisplay = day + "/" + month + "/" + year;
      //  mDisplayDate.setText ( date );
        }
    }
```

**In styles.xml**

```
 <style name="DatePickerDialogTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog">
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    </style>
```